# AJAX Post to ASP.NET MVC Controller action method - Null parameters

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to post with AJAX a string array with some data to my controller. It's just plain text, and my controller is always receiving a null parameter. I understand i shouldn't stringify since i don't use a model or viewmodel.

I searched other questions but most refer to forms and use viewmodel properties.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstAjax(string[] listValues)
{
    //TODO
    return Json("Reached the controller", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I added that JSON return to check if I was actually hitting the controller and I receive the message on my view.

**AJAX POST**

```
var listValues = [];
listElements.each(function (index, element) {
    listValues.push(element.innerText);
});

var serviceURL = '/Products/FirstAjax';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: listValues,
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});

function successFunc(data, status) {
    alert(data);
}

function errorFunc() {
    alert('error');
}
```

Since my list is sortable with drag & drop, the `listValues` is filled with the text value of the `<li>` items in the order when the button is clicked.

**View**

```
<div class="demo">

  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Cat</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Dog</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Tiger</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" onclick="display_array();">Ajax Post!</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: In your ajax, for your data, try this - "data : {listValues: listValues}". The first parameter in the curly brackets being the parameter in controller and second one being your javascript array.

Comment: Thanks @Daniaal, that worked!

Comment: dam i should have gave it as an answer! Oh well glad it worked amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write your Ajax POST method as follows:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var listValues = [];
    listElements.each(function (index, element) {
          listValues.push(element.innerText);
    });

    var serviceURL = '/Products/FirstAjax';

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: serviceURL,
       data: {listValues: listValues},
       contentType: 'application/json'
       success: successFunc,
       error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
       alert(data);
    }

    function errorFunc() {
       alert('error');
    }
});
```

**Hope this will solve your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax options to:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {listValues: listValues},
    ...
});
```

the reason is: server is expecting a posted object/query string that's same naming with parameters. the `data` is converted to `listValues=...&otherParams=...` in query string. if you post an array without specifying parameter name, JQuery cannot map them correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need `contentType` as `application/json` and use `JSON.stringify` to convert JavaScript object to JSON string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify({ listValues: listValues}),
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```